# Install self-hosted agent with managed service account?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to install a self-hosted agent using a managed service account (MSA)?
Or is password input required when setting the service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You couldn’t directly connect an azure devops agent to Azure Devops Service with MSA.

Azure Devops Service supports to use **PAT or Alternate Credentials** (‘alt’ authentication method).

Azure Devops On-premise also supports ‘**negotiate**’ authentication method (Kerberos or NTLM).

It could be useful to know that the PAT token is only used during the initial configuration of the agent.

When the PAT expires or needs to be renewed, the agent will remain connected without issues.

If the agent runs as service mode, you could also configure the “logon account” in local service or [re-configure the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent).

Here is a doc about  [the agent auth-type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#required-options)